# How to handle mail partial attribute that isn't always passed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a mailer partial that supports a passed-in attribute if present, but doesn't require it. Unfortunately, if I don't include the attribute, an exception is raised because to call for that attribute, I need to invoke a method with the same name:

Mailer Template:

`<%= render partial: 'partials/foobar', first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith', phone_number: '555-555-4444' %>`

`foobar` Partial:

```
<%= first_name %>
<%= last_name %>
<%= phone_number %>
```

If I don't include, say, `phone_number` in the partial insert statement:

`<%= render partial: 'partials/foobar', first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith' %>`

then an exception will be raised because `phone_number` was not passed in, so the template will have no method named `phone_number` present.

What's a good way to account for "optional" partial parameters like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in optional parameters as nil:

```
<%= render partial: 'partials/foobar', first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith', phone_number: nil %>
```

Then add a check in the view for the value of phone_number or just print out nil value which will leave a blank line.

```
<% if phone_number %>
  <%= phone_number %>
<% end %>
```

Another option is to check if phone_number is defined.

```
<% if defined? phone_number %>
  <%= phone_number %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your other option is exactly the sort of thing I was hoping for. I don't want to have to pass `nil` in every time I render the partial, but checking that it's `defined?` would be very low-impact. Thank you so much!